# Adding Firestore to my project give an error to my Realtime Database Queries

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been using Firebase Real-time Database in my project for quite some time now. Recently I added the pod for Firestore to use it together with the other database and all my queries and only the queries for Real-time Database are getting the following error: "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'".

If I uninstall the pod everything comes back to normal with absolutely no errors.
This is how I was using the code before: (working)

```
func retriveObjects() {
    ref.child("Dinner").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let allPosts = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        for (_, item) in allPosts {
            if let itemCount = item["itemCount"] as? String {
                print(itemCount)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this line is giving me the error:

```
if let itemCount = item["itemCount"] as? String
```

What can I do to make it work again but keeping both databases?

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Ambiguous+use+of+%27subscript%27) on the error. This has been covered many times before.

Comment: I’ve been searching for hours and didn’t find anything about installing Cloud Firestore to cause this problem. If you have any ideas please let me know, It is much appreciate it, cos I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with firestore. It's because `item` is `AnyObject`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I managed to sort it out defining the value in for loop and use it afterwords. Trying to understand: Was I using a bad code practice? Because I it worked fine before without any errors until I installed Firestore and removing it cause error to go away. (hence my confusion). I understand it got nothing to do with Firestore, but code update, strict syntax? Just so I know what I was doing wrong before.

Comment: The only problem was your attempt to treat `item` as a dictionary when its type was `AnyObject`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All works smoothly now. And I also understand the problem! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the value of the snapshot is being cast as a Dictionary of [String: AnyObject] and then you're trying to use item as a Dictionary but it's cast to AnyObject (which is not a dictionary). In other words item["itemCount"] doesn't work for AnyObject.

It's unclear what is throwing that error but we have a number of projects with both and it's not throwing that error. You may want to consider changing the code up a bit;

```
self.ref.child("Dinner").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for post in allPosts {
        let itemCount = post.childSnapshot(forPath: "itemCount").value as? String ?? "No Count"
        print(itemCount)
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to do it exactly like this, the only difference is that I am making a reference of "let value = post.value as! [String: Any]" before the "let itemCount= ..." so I can use my code.